# How to retrieve external IP of GCP Windows instances using Instance Metadata?

Tags: windows, powershell, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I need to retrieve the external IP of some GCP Windows instances.

I tried requesting Instance Metadata (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata).

The endpoint for external IP is http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip

This is working on Linux instances using curl:

```
$ curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip
35.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

However, I couldn't make it work on Windows instances using powershell:

```
> (Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Headers @{"Metadata-Flavor"="Google"} "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip").Content
51
53
46
50
49
46
46
57
49
57
46
55
```

I tried it with different instances using windows-2019 and windows-2016 public images.

The instances were launched using standard gcloud commandline:

```
gcloud compute instances create $instance-name \
    --image-project windows-cloud \
    --image-family windows-2019 \
    --machine-type n1-standard-1 \
    --boot-disk-size 50 \
    --boot-disk-type pd-ssd \
    --zone europe-west1-b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason `Invoke-WebRequest` ignores `Content-Type: application/text` in response and treats it as an array of bytes.

You could either convert bytes to string:

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString(
    (Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{'Metadata-Flavor'='Google'} -Uri 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip').Content
)
```

or use `Invoke-RestMethod`:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{'Metadata-Flavor'='Google'} -Uri 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo!
I guess the easiest (and faster way) would be to install [CURL for Windows](https://curl.haxx.se/windows/), then process the metadata as it is defined in the Google Docs for [Storing and Retrieving Metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata), and finally if power shell is a must, then you can always visit the [Google Cloud Tools for Power Shell](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-powershell/), but sometimes the easiest approach is the better, and almost all examples in Google Cloud are cURL based.

Hope this may be of use to you!
Happy scripting